# Añadir espacios en blanco entre el texto con php

Tags: php

estoy comenzando en el mundo de la programación y me he topado con un ejercicio que no sé hacer y me gustaría recibir algo de ayuda para poder avanzar, el ejercicio es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A ver si alguna persona me puede echar una mano para poder sacarlo.
Gracias.

Comment: En programación, nadie sabe cómo hacer cada cosa, se van creando soluciones sobre la marcha. Te invito a intentar resolver el problema, luego nos compartes tu código si tienes algún error en específico.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]  y de paso realiza el [tour], las preguntas exponiendo solo enunciados de ejercicio que no vienen acompañadas de algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan cerradas, te invito a tratar algo y posterior venir a preguntar

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Las preguntas pidiendo sugerencias, ejemplos, o que simplemente **hagan el ejercicio** no son bien recibidas. El primer paso para aprender un lenguaje es consultar su documentación. Entra a [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/index.php)